Split fix amount into a specified number of cells
This is for accounting purpose
I have one single amount example 100_000.
I want Excel to split this amount into multiple small amounts but that
amount should be split into 365 rows and in the end total figure should be exactly 100_000.
I have tried =rand and =rand(between) but did not got the desire result

What is the number 1,00,000? what do the oddly placed commas stand for?

Well it's for accounting purposes, so I didn't want him to have accountability problems with bad syntax. If it would have been for other purposes then I guess it would have fine fine.

@Elerium115 - Do look up the Indian Numbering System. You'll be surprised that 1,00,000 is the standard way of writing 100,000 in India. In a similar vein to European countries writing it with periods, i.e. 100.000.

I've changed the question to be in ISO format, so as no to offend the Europeans.

It's not about offending anyone. If you open Excel and you type =1,00,000  int results in a syntax error

@Elerium115 - I expect the OP was entering the number in SO and not Excel.

Literal from the question before being edited: "I have one single amount example 1,00,000 I want Excel to split this amount into multiple small amounts" If you put the amount 1,00,000 into Excel it results in a format error, which was what my comment was about.

It is 100K and not 100 means 100000 which is 1,00,000

See? It's still not clear what the intended number was, although is not relevant to the question. An algorithm to split it will still work if the number is different, is just that the result will be different. As is now, it's still an error in excel (the underscore is not a valid thousands separator) but at this point it no longer matters.

=LET(
    total, 100,
    rows, 10,
    min,1,
    max,50,
    baseArray, RANDARRAY(rows,1,min,max,TRUE),
    scaledArray, ROUND(baseArray / SUM(baseArray) * total, 0),
    diff, total - SUM(scaledArray),
    adjustedArray, scaledArray + SIGN(diff) * (SEQUENCE(rows) <= ABS(diff)),
    adjustedArray)

=LET(
    // define the total
    total, 100,
    // define the number of rows
    rows, 10,
    // the lowest random number (sort of)
    min,1,
    // the highest random number (sort of)
    max,50,     
    // Create a random array specified size rows with numbers from min to max
    baseArray, RANDARRAY(rows,1,min,max,TRUE),
    // Adjust the array by scaling it so its sum is the same as total (or close to it anyway)
    scaledArray, ROUND(baseArray / SUM(baseArray) * total, 0),
    // Check if there is a difference between the total of
    // the scaledArray and total due to rounding differences
    diff, total - SUM(scaledArray),
    // Adjust the new array with the calculated diff per row
    adjustedArray, scaledArray + SIGN(diff) * (SEQUENCE(rows) <= ABS(diff)),
    adjustedArray)

It's not perfect and the min and max numbers as defined can be adjusted when fixing the rounding issues and in some cases it's possible to get a negative number (when the min is defined as 0 or 1) but it's close enough for most purposes I think.

Nice @Michal . Care to take us through the formula and explain?

@jkpieterse - edited with comments

Here's one way to do it in Excel 2016.
My apologies for the lazy method (it uses adjusted min/max, though within the your range.)

Though cell references could be used directly for this simple task, naming them is preferable.
Instead of filling down, enter these as array formulas: Create an array formula - Microsoft Support

Method:

Set the parameters min/max/total and name the cells.
To get 364 random numbers, select 364 cells (D1-D364 in the example), enter the following in the formula bar
=RAND()*(max_-min_)+min_ and press Shift + Control + Enter
Name the range as step_1
In a second column, we will have the first cell  (F1 in the example) as: =total_-SUM(F2:F365) to match the total.
Select 364 cells below (F2:F365 in the example) and enter the following with Shift + Control + Enter:
=ROUND(step_1 / SUM(step_1) * (total_ - min_), 2) here we adjust the random values to fall within the desired range.

Hope this helps, or at least gives you an idea.



Name
Refers to:




max_
=Sheet2!$A$4


min_
=Sheet2!$A$2


step_1
=Sheet2!$D$1:$D$364


total_
=Sheet2!$A$6





Nice use of VSTACK, more elegant than my solution.  Not sure why I wrote my formula to split the number into integers so your solution as presented is more flexible.

Thank you @Michal! BTW, I learn from many of your answers.

Hi Sir you got this answer but I dont know where and how to you that function can you guide because if it word that my many days work can be be sorted in a single day

I am using office 2016  and clearly I do not know how to use this method please can you  guide with actual method that is total should be Rs.100000 /-  and should have random figure for all the 365 rows min amount will be 500 and max amount will be 1000

It looks like RANDARRAY is available in Office 2021 and later only. Let me see what could work under 2016. Could you please confirm the mix/max? 365 x 500 would be larger than 100_000.

min 100 and max 275 or 280 which ever possible for get net amount total upto 100000

Thanks @DeepakBhanushali, I'll give it a try today or tomorrow.

min 150 and max 300 or 280 whichever possible to get the net amount total to 100000 Sir One more thing result is must that is Rs. 100000  and it should be random roundoff amount for 365 days which are fix not the min or max

Sir Great to get atleast near by rest I can edit you are great sir @nkalvi thank you  so much
